# Button to download HTML of a page

Tags: html

Is there a way to have a button/link and when you click on it, it will take the current page location and download an HTML version of it? It will be an iframe too, and the link should just download the iframe's content. Thanks!

Comment: Like Right Click > Save As... ? What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: In Chrome, Ctrl S will save the source. Is that all you want?

Comment: You'd need a server side language to serialise the HTML, zip it, and then display the right headers to force download dialogue.

Comment: "they want a button that they can just click and have it save a zip file"...note that clients often ask for really stupid things. That said, you could create a link that passes the url as a querystring to a back-end script that runs on the server that will zip the file then stream it to the browser which would then prompt the file save dialogue. Or, you could show the client how to use SAVE AS... that's built into their browser.

Comment: Ah yeah well it's kind of complicating actually but it's for the Facebook iframes, they want to have a button to just download the HTML version of the iframe only, so right click > save as wouldn't work because it would downlaod the facebook page as well. And I wouldn't even know where to begin to do the other way you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a simple script that takes the file name as a param and generates a zip. [Here](http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php) is an example in PHP.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work, but it looks like it's exactly what I'm trying to do. Lets say I'm trying to download the source code of a page with a URL like this: `somesite.com/someslug/welcome`, how would I have it download that? I have it so far to run using a form but it's not creating a zip file anywhere.

Comment: check that the script has write permissions on destination directory. also, you can check the value of the  $result variable returned by the function call to see if it succeeded.

Comment: I uncommented the line below `//debug` and clicked the button, it just went to a blank page.. =/

Comment: if you have a form, use the form data to build the $files_to_zip array parameter in the usage example. $files_to_zip = array(<put in file names>); It worked for me. Make sure that directory is writable.

Answer (score 2):

The following JavaScript will take the current document and provide it as a download link. Tested in Chrome, not sure about others. Keep in mind that IE has limits for DataURI size. Furthermore, you'll lose your external images/CSS/etc, unless you inject the `base` tag into the top of the `head` tag (or find some other way to roll in resources):

```
// create the link to trigger download
// you could alternatively fetch an existing tag and update it
var a = document.createElement('a');

// send as type application/octet-stream to force download, not in browser
a.href = 
    "data:application/octet-stream;base64," +
    btoa("<html>"+ document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML + 
    "</html>");

a.innerText = "Download this page";

// put the link wherever you want
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

EDIT: also doesn't provide a filename, or a .htm at the end of the download link... hmph. Those things can only really be provided by the Content-Disposition header, and that requires sending a request off to the server, so... not a fantastic user experience, but the easiest way to get the *exact* page state as the user sees it.